set noshowcmd to only hide partial commands
In normal mode when I press Space (which is my leader), Vim/NeoVim always displays <20> in the command area. I find this visually distracting.
I know that I can disable it with set noshowcmd, but that would also disable the selected number of characters in visual mode. Is there a trick that I can hide the partial command only?

This is not possible

Better investigate WHY you get that unexpected behavior than ask for a way to hide it.

@romainl It's not an unexpected behaviour. If showcmd is set, you will see the partial command. In the case of the leader key (which is space), <20> is the hex value. I wanted to know how configurable the behaviour is.

@ChristianBrabandt Thanks, that's what I assumed too. I haven't contributed anything myself to vim yet, but I'm happy to explore the code to raise a PR ? Probably I will discuss this in the proper mailing list.

Hmm, it looks like I misread your question. It is not about <20> itself (which is a weird way of displaying <Space> considering how other characters are displayed) but about partial commands. Sorry for the noise.

Honestly, this seems a bit like a niche feature. We had users before complaining that space is not visible in showcmd so the <20> was added around late 7.4 release
